# Destroy tkinter button

Tags: python, tkinter

I created an application in Tkinter Python that searches an archive for several licenses and then groups the results in worldlists. After finding a license, a button appears which, if I press it, shows me the result in a ScrolledText. The idea is that I cannot delete the buttons that appear (to restart) after I have made a search. Can someone help me to solve this situation.
How can I destroy the **mit_bt**?

```
def print_to_textbox_Mit(wordlist):
    if len(wordlist) >= 1:
        mit_button()

def mit_button():
    mit_bt = tk.Button(window, text= " M I T ", relief="groove", command=mit_print_text, activebackground="#800020").place(x=10, y=10)

def mit_print_text():
    text_box.delete("1.0", tk.END)
    text_box.insert("0.0", "\n            !!!!!! MIT !!!!!!")
    for lines in wordlist:
        text_box.insert("end", "\n"+lines)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def print_to_textbox_Mit(wordlist):
    if len(wordlist) >= 1:
        mit_button()

def mit_button():
    mit_bt = tk.Button(
        window,
        text= " M I T ",
        relief="groove",
        activebackground="#800020",
    )
    # configure your button's 'command' after declaring it above
    mit_bt.configure(command=lambda b = mit_bt: mit_print_text(b))
    # using a lambda here allows us to pass an argument to the 'command' callback!
    mit_bt.place(x=10, y=10)

def mit_print_text(button):  # pass your button as an argument to this function
    text_box.delete("1.0", tk.END)
    text_box.insert("0.0", "\n            !!!!!! MIT !!!!!!")
    for lines in wordlist:
        text_box.insert("end", "\n"+lines)
    # once you no longer need the button, call 'place_forget' on it to remove it
    button.place_forget()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the button to go away and your mit_print_text function results to be the only thing displaying, you can add "mit_bt.destroy()" at the end of that function. As JRiggles commented, you would have to pass it in.

```
def mit_print_text(mt_bt):
    text_box.delete("1.0", tk.END)
    text_box.insert("0.0", "\n            !!!!!! MIT !!!!!!")
    for lines in wordlist:
        text_box.insert("end", "\n"+lines)
    mit_bt.destroy()
```

Comment: `mit_bt` is outside the scope of `mit_print_text()`

Comment: @JRiggles see edit. Should work just as well if he passes it in

Comment: Yeah, this should work - I came to the same conclusion in my answer